# VB find newest document in mongo

Tags: mongodb, vb.net

I can find the collection:

```
Imports MongoDB.Driver
..
Dim client As MongoClient
client = New MongoClient("mongodb+srv://...")
Dim db = client.GetDatabase("wetterstation")
Dim collection = db.GetCollection(Of BsonDocument)("akkus")
```

I tested it with (copied from another question)

```
Dim q = New BsonDocument()
Dim f = Builders(Of BsonDocument).Projection.Include("_id")
Dim list = collection.Find(q).Project(f).ToList
```

then I get a list of id's of the collection.
But how can I get the newest document?

Comment: I am not familiar with the MongoDB.Driver but the query would be `db.getSiblingDB("wetterstation").getCollection("akkus").find({}).sort({_id: -1}).limit(1)` or if `db.getSiblingDB("wetterstation").getCollection("akkus").findOne({}).sort({_id: -1})`. Note, `findOne` should return a return a single document rather than a `List(Of BsonDocument)`

Comment: Thanks for your input, I have Syntax problems. 
```Dim doc = collection.findOne({}).sort({_id: -1})``` 
-> findone is no member of "IMongoCollection(of BsonDocument).
also _id is only accepted as string "_id".
Do you have an idea what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested myself but I reckon this modification of your snippet should do the work:

```
Dim collection As IMongoCollection(Of BsonDocument) = db.GetCollection(Of BsonDocument)("akkus")
    
Dim filter As FilterDefinition(Of BsonDocument) = New BsonDocument
Dim projection As ProjectionDefinition(Of BsonDocument) = Builders(Of BsonDocument).Projection.Include("_id")
Dim sorter As SortDefinition(Of BsonDocument) = Builders(Of BsonDocument).Sort.Descending("_id")

Dim list = collection.Find(filter).Project(projection).Sort(sorter).Limit(1).ToList
```

If you sort by descending "**_ids**" the first occurrence should be the newest one as well, as said in comments. Then you just would need to take the first appearence and there you go.